# Using Requests GET to get the results of a form with input parameters

Tags: python-2.7, get, python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests GET method to get the results of this form:

```
FORM ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data' method=POST action="../cgi-bin/DktRpt.pl?515287285576685-L_1_0-1"
```

but with this input values on:

```
INPUT TYPE='checkbox' NAME='list_of_parties_and_counsel' id='list_of_parties_and_counsel' value='on' CHECKED
```

How do I tell the get method to include `'list_of_parties_and_counsel' = on`? I tried including `params = {'list_of_parties_and_counsel': 'on'}` but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the url as I am not sure exactly what you are asking? The requests is a post so you need to post to the url not get

Comment: I could share it, but it is behind a login. The page is a submit form for a report. If I were to do a post instead of a get, would the response.content be the content of the report that I am trying to access?

Comment: I just need the url

Comment: https://ecf.nyed.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/DktRpt.pl?382380

Answer (score 0):

It is a [multipart-form request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

[image]

So you need to pass a dict or tuples of key/value pairs:

```
import requests

files = [("login","foo"),("key","pass"),("clcode","yourclcode"),("button1","Login")]
url = "https://ecf.nyed.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/DktRpt.pl?382380"
with requests.Session() as s:
   r = s.post(url, files=files)
```

That is an example of the login page, you will have to look at chrome and monitor that particular form post and do the same.